# Validar model antes de inserir no banco

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api

Estou desenvolvendo uma WebAPI usando EntityFramework6.

Antes de realizar um INSERT no banco, gostaria de validar o model que está vindo via requisição (acredito ser fundamental), porém não tenho experiência nas boas práticas da validação de dados e gostaria de saber se o EF6 disponibiliza algum recurso padrão para tal.

Eu pensei em fazer uma classe que será responsável por receber uma especialização qualquer de um model, bater os tipos de dado com o model criado pelo Framework e caso os tipos de dados/tamanho estiverem de acordo, retorna um bool pro método que a chamou dizendo que pode seguir com o insert.

O problema disso é que me faria escrever muito código que eu só escreveria se não houvesse um jeito mais seguro e rápido de fazer.

Alguma ideia de como seguir?

Comment: Validar que você diz seria algo como, por exemplo, um campo não aceita valores negativos? Se for a obrigação de fazer isso passa a ser do seu dominio.

Comment: @GabrielColetta gostaria de, por exemplo, receber um model do tipo cliente e validar se esse model possui todos os dados obrigatórios da tabela do banco, além de validar se o username não tem espaço, se a senha atende ao critério, etc.

Comment: @Csorgo dá uma olhada na minha resposta, vai ficar mais bacana ainda seu exemplo, e você nao precisa ficar fazendo if em todo post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api)

A própria linguagem fornece uma maneira de validar o model antes de inserir no banco através de annotations utilizando a lib `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` no model e usando `ModelState.IsValid` no método que recebe o POST:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("user/")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(user newUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        new UserController();
        db.user.Add(newUser);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Usuário validado e adicionado com sucesso.")),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            ReasonPhrase = "User validated and inserted successfully."
            };
        }
        else
        {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            Content = new StringContent(string.Format("Erro na validação de dados.")),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            ReasonPhrase = "Data Validation failed."
        };
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class user
{
    public user()
    {
        //Código do construtor
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string USERNAME { get; set; }

    [StringLength(8)]
    public string PASSWORD { get; set; }

    public string EMAIL { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Há uma forma bacana de validar o model sem ficar sujando muito o código:
Crie uma classe chamada **ModelStateValidationActionFilterAttribute.cs**

```
public class ModelStateValidationActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

        if (!modelState.IsValid)
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                 .CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
    }
}
```

Aí nas suas chamadas basta decorar os métodos:

```
[HttpPost]
[ModelStateValidationActionFilter]
public IHttpActionResult Post(object model)
{
  // Do something here ;)
}
```

Abaixo segue meu artigo completo sobre esse assunto.

https://medium.com/@thiagoloureiro/validando-models-em-webapis-e2471949b49c

Comment: Bacana cara, será bem util na minha aplicação! Obrigado pela dica!

Answer (score 0):

Até onde sei se pode usar as annotation de validação normalmente em suas viewsmodels, com isso você ira realizar a validação na requisição.
Aconselho o uso do `ModelState.IsValid` no controller para validar o modelo.
você também pode usar o código abaixo para recuperar os campos com inválidos.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var message = string.Join(" | ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
                throw new Exception(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por parte. Quando você disse "model que vem da requisição" eu assumo que é um Dto, um ViewModel ou qualquer nome para um objeto que apenas carrega atributos. Não é interessante utilizar esses objetos como suas entidades do Model ou Dominio para evitar o acoplamento da camada Model com a camada Controller. Para validar esses dados de entradas, você pode utilizar Data Annotation assim como o Nilton falou.

Agora pensando que já estamos falando a nível de domínio. Não é obrigação do Entity Framework fazer a validação sobre esse assunto. A obrigação é da sua entidade. Seguindo o paradigma da orientação a objetos, quem deve validar a classe Cliente é o próprio Cliente.

Recomendo você utilizar um padrão pouco reconhecido por nome, mas utilizado em bastante lugar, que é o Good Citizen Pattern. Nesse padrão, seu objeto deve **validar se o seu próprio estado está consistente**, se tornando um bom cidadão.

Existe várias maneiras de fazer isso, por exemplo:

- O construtor de uma classe serve muito mais do que fazer injeção de
  dependencia, ele deveria ser utilizado para deixar a classe em um
  estado válido sempre que possível. Haverá casos onde apenas o construtor não é suficiente.
- É comum (mesmo que não seja especificado diretamente no good citizen pattern) fazer um contrato de validação, por exemplo IValidated. Nesse caso faça com que todas classes implemente um método de validação, assim antes do Entity começar fazer o seu papel, você consegue validar a entidade e, se possível, até recuperar ela se necessário.

Exemplo:

```
var meuNovoCliente = new Cliente(nome: "Gabriel Coletta", idade: 23);
var clienteValido = meuNovoCliente.Validar();
if(clienteValido) { 
    //chamar a camada que faz o INSERT, por exemplo;
}
```

Comment: isso ai me cheira gambiarra, não seria melhor lançar uma exceção na construção do objeto? esta exceção poderia ser tratada no controler para retornar uma mensagem, ou status code caso uma requisição http pro client.

Comment: No caso o Data Annotation na camada Controller faria isso, como o Nilton representou e eu reafirmei a eficacia. Porém, validar o dominio apenas na entrada de alguns atributos é falho, já que eu posso modificar meu objeto em outra camada.

Comment: eu não conheço C#, mas por exemplo em java, eu posso impedir que o estado seja alterado sem passar por validações, excluindo getters e setters, ou seja, não ter dumb classes, eu poderia fazer isso em C#?

Comment: Tem sim, como no java, no C# temos os mesmo acessores, mas eles são acoplados diretamente no field, o que chamados de properties. Devido a isso o getters e setters sempre existem, mas eu posso deixar eles privados ou criar uma variável readonly, ou até mesmo criar ela imutável (vide implementação).

Answer (score 0):

Fora a resposta aceita, existe ainda a classe [ValidationResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult(v=vs.110).aspx) que poderia ser usada para validar seu objeto.

```
var resultado = new List<ValidationResult>();
var contexto = new ValidationContext(_SeuObjeto, null, null);
Validator.TryValidateObject(_SeuObjeto, contexto, resultado, true);
```

Você poderia criar um projeto na infraestrutura para fazer validações com objeto genéricos.

[Veja um simples exemplo.](https://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/simple-validation-with-data-annotations/)